# Upgrade error from 4.6 to 4.7 - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, 4.7, 4.6

I'm trying to upgrade, following the official guide, but when I get to the url : 
wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1

I get the folowing error message :

```
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => 
SELECT
   option_value.id          as id,
   option_value.label       as label,
   option_value.value       as value,
   option_value.name        as name,
   option_value.description as description,
   option_value.weight      as weight,
   option_value.is_active   as is_active,
   option_value.is_default  as is_default
FROM
   civicrm_option_value_fr_FR  as option_value,
   civicrm_option_group_fr_FR  as option_group  WHERE option_group.id = option_value.option_group_id  AND option_group.name = 'languages' ORDER BY weight [nativecode=1449 ** The user specified as a definer ('pui'@'%') does not exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => 
SELECT
   option_value.id          as id,
   option_value.label       as label,
   option_value.value       as value,
   option_value.name        as name,
   option_value.description as description,
   option_value.weight      as weight,
   option_value.is_active   as is_active,
   option_value.is_default  as is_default
FROM
   civicrm_option_value_fr_FR  as option_value,
   civicrm_option_group_fr_FR  as option_group  WHERE option_group.id = option_value.option_group_id  AND option_group.name = 'languages' ORDER BY weight [nativecode=1449 ** The user specified as a definer ('pui'@'%') does not exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="
SELECT
   option_value.id          as id,
   option_value.label       as label,
   option_value.value       as value,
   option_value.name        as name,
   option_value.description as description,
   option_value.weight      as weight,
   option_value.is_active   as is_active,
   option_value.is_default  as is_default
FROM
   civicrm_option_value_fr_FR  as option_value,
   civicrm_option_group_fr_FR  as option_group  WHERE option_group.id = option_value.option_group_id  AND option_group.name = 'languages' ORDER BY weight [nativecode=1449 ** The user specified as a definer ('pui'@'%') does not exist]"]
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to Civi... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a problem if you're trying to move the Civi database from a server to another (in my case from production to my localhost).

You need to change the db user in the mysqldump file. 
We did it using a script and the sed command